# django email, customize helo parameter

Tags: django, django-email

I am using django email to send emails in the following manner:

```
email = EmailMessage(
    'Object',
    'body',
    my_from_addr,
    args.emails,
    [],
    reply_to=['my_from_addr'],
    #ehlo=settings.EMAIL_HELO,
)
```

I need to set the helo/ehlo parameter to comply with the email server, I didn't found a variable django uses, is there any good way of doing so?

Comment: what is the email backend in settings that you use

Comment: I haven't set any settings about the backend, only the email host and port, so it must be the default backend